# linking database tables

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm wading deeper and deeper into unknown territory with a project I'm working on.  As part of it I have to have a login creation system for both admins and users.  Admins need to be able to create products and users need to be able to purchase the products so the details need to be linked to their accounts.  I'm a bit lost as to where I should start.  There is lots of info out there about sql databases but what is the logic behind what I'm trying to achieve?
I'm currently working with php and html forms to collect the data.

Comment: What specifically do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need is to create a mysql database, I will suggest to use navicat as database editor.

Then I would suggest you to create 2 tables, category,item.

Simplest table structure

category:

1. ID (category unique ID)
2. Name (not NULL, varchar)

item:

1. ID (unique ID, database AI (auto increment), basically it give ID = prevID + 1)
2. Name (not NULL, varchar)
3. Price (integer 11)
4. category (the ID of root category)

Then what you need to do is using intergrated mysql functions, I suggest you use [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) as your guide how to use database with PHP, send data to database and recieve data from database.

And basically this is it.

**EDIT[1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp):** So basically you need to restructure your database.

Admin table:

1. ID
2. Name

User table:

1. ID
2. Name

Item table:

1. ID
2. Name
3. Shop ID
4. Admin ID

Shop Table:

1. ID
2. Name

Sales table:

1. ID
2. Item ID
3. User ID

When Admin ID=x chooses Shop id=x1 and creates Item with shop=x1 and admin=x with unique ID=x3, a user can buy Item ID=x3 and when it is sold you either

1. can remove Item ID=x3 from Item table and insert into Sales new record with Item id=x3
2. or you can add another collumn (quantity) and with PHP minus the quantity user is buying and then put the quanitty in sales table.

Comment: And how do I go about keeping them in sync with each other?  When the admin creates a venue I want that shop, I want the shop only associated with that admin and then the items only associated with the shop.  I understand how to call for the info from the tables but concerned when it comes to splitting data among the different tables.

Comment: What do you mean by splitting data among the different tables?

Comment: Admin/User Table, Shop Table, Item Table, Sales Table, etc.  The part I'm unsure of is when creating an item for example, it will need to be associated with the accociated shop so that details can be edited or retreved for each but how do I make sure that the Admin with the ID number 243 who created the shop with the ID 36 that sells the item with the ID 3986 has been sold to the user with the ID 995 and that the data is easy to track with each other?  If I'm not making sense I apologise

Comment: Very easy I will edit in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on the basic logic and properties of data before thinking about the implementation. Something to start with is what kind of products are you looking at, what kinds of properties will you need to associate with each product. Then you need to think the business logic on going about implementing features like the basic database set up, the front end set up, most importantly the security features and payment features. You really should have a strong idea and can visualise roughly as to what you really want and changes can always be made along the road.